# Check that a value is a valid color for tk tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a class with a variable that supposed to hold a color that will later be used as a [color in tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkLib/GetColor.htm), and since its value isn't shown to the user as a string, it can hold either words, or an Hex RGB number (for example #FF00FF or "magenta").

When I create an object I want to check that the color is valid. Is there a way to check that a certain value is an valid color for tcl and tk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the command `winfo rgb .` which will try to convert the string to an RGB value. If the string is invalid, the command will throw an error which you can catch.